# how to Sum in LINQ using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am working with following sample data but my linq returns error result, please help

### Sample data

```
id amount
1  -500
2   500
1   500
1  -500
```

---

### Expected Output

```
1 -500
2 500
```

### My output

```
1 -1000
1 500
2 500
```

Comment: what have you done with your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.id)
                 .Select(x => new { id = x.Key, Amount = x.Sum(z => z.amount) });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do summation and grouping both , So

```
  var output = from item in data
          group item by item.Id
          into g
          select new { Id = g.Key, amount = g.Sum(item => item.amount) };
```